# .company vs. .com domain - should I use domain forwarding?

Tags: seo, domains, top-level-domains, domain-forwarding, branding

I bought an online shop that came with a short but not brand-specific `.company` domain, but I would prefer to use a brand-specific `.com` domain. I was told that I cannot change it unless I'm willing to pay a lot.

Here are my questions:

- How much better is a `.com` domain (with regard to SEO, credibility, and memorability), and how important is it that the brand is part of the domain (`example.company` vs. `brand-example.com`)?
- I have not done any marketing yet, so I don't have links pointing to my site as far as I'm aware. Would it make sense at all to get the `.com` domain I want and just redirect it to my `.company` domain (without masking) and then use that in my marketing? Or would that just cause unnecessary confusion or SEO disadvantages?

Comment: If you got the .com domain you want, wouldn't you redirect the .company to it, not vice versa? And since your site isn't finished yet, with no inbound links, you can just phase in your new domain and not worry about it. If your exact domain is too expensive (widgets.com) just get creative with it (shinywidgets.com).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest redirecting the ".com" to the ".company" to benefit from the innovation of a new domain name, which is more eye catchy. It is what I did with jovenet.com